# Writing files to SD card from an embedded system

Tags: c, embedded, atmel, atmelstudio

I am using a Atmel SAME54 microprocessor that has SDHC capabilities, using the Atmel Studio 8 IDE. However, the driver Atmel gives is to write raw bytes into the SD card. For my purposes, I am attempting to write data as .lam files, which will basically be a text file.

Is there any way to encode a header of a file so that I can directly write a file into memory and have it be recognized as a file on OS platform (Windows/Linux)? If I directly write "Hello, world!" into memory, it works, but can't be read from Windows file manager.

Initially, I’m thinking that I can encode a text file header in order to let the computer know that there is a file here. But I am having lots of trouble searching for this as it seems text files don’t have any headers? This seems silly. I even wrote a method to write my data as XML data, writing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
    “Hello, world!”
</Data>
```

And this isn’t readable either. I then was seeing if I can use `fopen`/`fprintf`/`fclose` within embedded systems, but this doesn’t seem to work either for what feel is obvious that there isn’t I/O memory within the system.

I’m at a loss if this is going to be doable to save memory as files. There obviously has to be a way to do this, so any clue as to how to do this? My current thought is to retarget the `fopen`/`fprintf`/`fclose` commands to use my abstracted SD_MMC commands for writing bytes of data. However, I feel I may run into the same issue as before.

Any help or resources would be appreciated.

Comment: I recommend that you find a suitable FAT driver for the card, and use it to treat the cards as any other FAT-formatted disk. Even if the driver doesn't come with the standard C functions for file-handling, it hopefully should be similar enough to be easy to use.

Comment: You need filesystem support in your code.  Try adapting the FatFs library in the Atmel Software Package.  https://github.com/atmelcorp/atmel-software-package/blob/master/lib/fatfs/README.fatfs.txt